# Laravel can't login using Auth::login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to login user with credentials which is being posted from other site. The app works:

1. User creates an account in other site or system finds the account by credentials user typed.
2. System redirects user to the laravel app which find the user by id which were sent from first app.
3. Laravel method finds a user by sent credential and find his data in db.
4. Calling function `Auth::login($user)`

and after 4th step nothing is happening even no error is showing. I have printed `$user` and its contents is user data from DB (object)

So where the problem could be? Snippet:

```
$this->_data['user'] = User::where('key', $hash);
        if ($this->_data['user']->count() > 0) {
            $user = $this->_data['user']->first();

            Auth::login($user);
        }
```

P.S.: its laravel 5.

EDIT:
it seems that somehow its working but not that way as expected. After this function I have checked login status with `Auth::check()` and it seems that user was connected but not properly... where the bug could be?

EDIT, full method::

http://pastebin.com/YKpjxytY

Comment: "user was connected but not properly" - what does it mean?

Comment: i dont even know - when I try to print `var_dump(Auth::user()->id);` i got the ID of the user when calling this method just after `Auth::login($user);` method. But if I go to the other page - im not logged in again. So it looks like Im being logged in and logged out just after logged in

Comment: Could you paste your app/Http/Kernel.php?

Comment: yeah, sure. http://pastebin.com/qsmUJWGT

Comment: What is the name of your primary key column in your users table?

Comment: `id` is the primary key.

Comment: Do you see session cookie set? Does $user->getAuthIdentifier() return the correct id?

Comment: yeah it returns me correct user id.

Comment: is it possible that Auth method does not work properly because user were redirected in that method from another page?

Comment: also, this the whole method if it would help you

Comment: redirect doesn't matter. when you login, user's id should be saved in session and later used to retrieve that user in next requests... Please check a few more things: 1. Do you see the session cookie? 2. dd(Session::all()) after Auth::login() and see if correct id is saved there. The variable name starts with login_

Comment: yeah, I can see this stuff - http://pastebin.com/GN2cFjkM but I'm missing `user`, `_previous` and `flash` variables with its contents. So this is the bug i think but how handle it?

Comment: Looks good, and then when you go to some other page after logging in and dd(Session::all()), do you see the login_* field? What user provider are you using? It's the value of "driver" parameter in your auth.php? Do you have model set correctly in your auth.php?

Comment: no, after I go to the other page `dd(Session::all())` shows me only `_token`. Also it not redirects me when I'm calling `Auth::login($user)`.  How to check what user provider script uses? This is not my script, I just have a mission to implement new login stuff. And model is `App\User` and in the controller I'm using the same one.

Comment: come on, you want help so make please try more. I'm asking the third time - do you see session cookie set during the request that logs user in and do you see it passed from the browser when you do the next request?

Comment: sorry about it. no, I can't see it. I can see the session in the page where it creates login. But when I go to the dashboard - session is gone.

Comment: hmm, another thing that could be wrong is session configuration - please check your config/session.php and see if domain is set to null and secure flag is set to false

Comment: yeah, both of them is the same as you said. is there any chance that I can pay for your help to make this thing work? we could communicate via  other service.

Comment: no. but I can have a look if the code is available somewhere as long as it's simple to get the app running

Comment: so i found the problem. you can call me stupid or I can splash my head to the wall. It was www VS non-www... Redirect were made to non www and I was checking in www version. So this problem is gone now. But the very next one is - why it not redirects me after login? As I gues `Auth::login($user);` should redirect user to the main page

Comment: No, it just logs user in, you need to redirect manually

Comment: but when I tried to make `redirect('/');` just after login - it didn't worked.

Comment: I don't see you doing redirect after login. Remember to do "return redirect()", not just call "redirect()"

Comment: ok thats helps me a lot. Thank you for everything.